LVM Raid5 replace+rebuild
I have a linux box for storage. From my notes, I set it up as:
# pvcreate /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
# vgcreate array /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
# lvcreate --type raid5 -l 100%FREE --name data array
# vgchange -ay array
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/array/data
# cat /etc/fstab | grep array
/dev/array/data /mnt/data ext4 defaults  0 2

Now drive sdb has died, no device is detected, nothing in dmesg and leaving it plugged in and it gets worryingly hot. It is a dead drive.
# lvscan
Couldn't find device with uuid ILT0MD-1BxM-gDR7-PJid-Vkrw-MBbZ-Y31i1t.
  inactive Original '/dev/array/data'

I have a replacement. How do I remove the failed (not failing, failed!) drive, add the replacement and rebuid the array?
I can't seem to remove references to the dead drive, but can't seem to do anything until it has gone, either:
# time vgreduce --removemissing --force array
  Couldn't find device with uuid ILT0MD-1BxM-gDR7-PJid-Vkrw-MBbZ-Y31i1t.
Killed

real    392m9.382s
user    20m0.648s
sys     9m16.664s


vgextend  Add a spare PV if one does not exist already.
lvconvert --repair vg/lv  Repair operation can replace failed RAID images even if the PV block devices are gone. Say yes to the full device resync  prompt. Note this is an operation on LVs, not VGs; repeat if you have multiple LVs.
vgreduce --removemissing vg  Remove missing is allowed after the array is repaired. LVM will stop complaining about the missing PV's UUID, remove the failed drive.
If desired, pvmove LVs between PVs. For example, if you did not have a spare drive bay, and attached some temporary storage.
Refer to examples specific to failed PVs.  For example, RHEL Logical Volumes,  9.19.2. Replacing a failed RAID device in a logical volume
